# While playing music in sync across nearby iOS devices, music did not play simultaneously (Multi Peer Connectivity)

Tags: ios, objective-c, streaming, multipeer-connectivity

We can connect up to 7 devices with multipeer framework connectivity.
I've followed this link: https://github.com/tonyd256/TDAudioStreamer‌ to do the streaming for the songs from 1 device to multiple iOS devices.

I would like to play music in sync across nearby iOS devices. I have created the app to play the music in sync with multiple devices.
I am getting very good results with 2-3 devices.

When I am playing 10 songs one after another with more than 3 devices with iOS 11 onwards, I am getting following issues:

1.) Host pause the song but all guests did not receive the pause action
2.) Sometimes Voice Breaking
3.) Not able to connect devices with each other
4.) Songs do not play in sync after pause action
5.) Song did not play in guest but it was showing it is playing
6.) Devices disconnecting while song was playing
7.) Connecting device issue

The major issues are 1 and 4.

Please help to solve above issues.

Answer (score 0):

Solving Problem #1 will be difficult without more information. What steps have you taken to debug this issue? Are the devices not receiving the "pause" command at all?

For Problem #4, I'd suggest sending the "Play" action along with a timestamp ~300 milliseconds into the future. Then add some logic for the devices to "Play" when that time arrives. This way, it won't matter if there is slight latency between devices when they receive the message, they'll all start playing at the same time as long as they receive the message within 300ms.